# Full text search query on two database with different query plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I have two databases on the same Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64)
The CIKK table merge replicated. There is a same FULL text indexes on both.
All of the indexes (Full text also) are the same.

I run the same query on both

```
select cikkszam 
from cikk 
where delstatus=1 
and webmegjel=1 
and contains(*,'"spi*"')
```

On the master database it takes 120 sec. on the Slave database it takes 0 sec.
The results are the same.
The problems is the query plan.
On the slow one, firstly uses an indexes (delstatus, webmegjel) and the result set is checked with the full text index. On the fast one it does the opposite.

A saved the query plans and the statistic plans also, but Stackoverflow only allow 2 links, so here the sqlplans.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zvcizijn1yxlrvj/plan1.sqlplan
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4yi0c1q2ly8spsk/plan2.sqlplan

What can be the solution to this?

Comment: Here are the statistic profiles
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3n6x44ssde0zfbv/stat1.csv
    https://www.dropbox.com/s/gfbsn8p32k4qi52/stat2.csv

Comment: Are the columns in indexes in the same order on both tables? If you specify a WITH(...) clause does it change how the query is executed?

Comment: Yes, indexes are the same

Comment: I have seen both of the execution plans and one of them seems to be using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. Sometimes already cached plan is the best plan for a query and using this RECOMPILE option comes up with a better plan at run time. Have a closer look at both of your queries once again and see if you notice the difference this time.

Comment: I just tried it with recompile. Before that it was the same. Nothing has been changed